# External harddrive not recognized when connected to asus laptop running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive, autoplay

I'm trying to connect a Beyondmicro 250 GB external USB NTFS hard drive, model number BMMDU2 with it's own power supply to a 64-bit version of Windows Vista on an Asus laptop, the error message i'm recieving is "Windows has stopped the device because it reported problems." The error code is 43. Autoplay does not run and the drive is not mapped. The same drive works fine on my desktop running xp and a friends computer also running 64-bit vista.

It seems there are still many avenues to pursue, but i couldn't find anyone with this exact question.

Alternatively, what is the best way to move past this? FTP or making a home network?

Comment: I assume this is a 2.5" hard drive. Sometimes the drive needs more power than 1 USB port can provide. Many cables provide a "Y" cable that you can use to plug into two separate ports to get sufficient power. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: no this is an older hard drive made a company called beyondmicro. it has it's own power supply. added to op.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to resolve this issue and am writing it up as perhaps one of the reasons BeyondMicro disapperaed. Thankfully i was able to use AIM to get most of the data to myself.